# Не могу запустить скрипт написанный на языке Python из файла Upload.py на сервере Abyss Web Server X1

Tags: python, python-3.x

у меня такой вопрос. Из книги Python программирование для начинающих автора Майк МакГрат в главе 8 "Обработка запросов", я пытался создать серверную программу на языке Python для обработки HTML-запросов. Проще говоря, я хочу написать программу, которая бы **загружала файл с локального компьютера на сервер**. На странице 150 в главе "Выгрузка файлов" описан простой и подробный код, как это можно реализовать. Перед тем как скопировать этот программный код и выполнить его, я (как было подробно описано в книге) скачал и установил веб-сервер Abyss Web Server X1. Далее к этому серверу я подключил Интерпретатор python версии Python 3.5.4. После этого, с помощью python, я вывел фразу "Hello world" на экран браузера. Это означает, что python работает корректно. Потом я скопировал, код из главы "Выгрузка файлов", но почему то сервер выдает ошибку:

**Error 500
Internal Server Error**

Я использовал разные версии python, но это не помогло решить проблему.

вот что говорят логи сервера:

**cgi.log**

```
  File "upload.py", line 6
    copy.write( upload.file.read() )
       ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
[06/May/2018:11:41:02 +0700]    CGI: [C:\Python35\python.exe upload.py ]    URI: /upload.py Broken pipe
```

**accsess.log**

```
::1 - - [06/May/2018:11:41:02 +0700] "POST /upload.py HTTP/1.1" 500 348 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
```

вот весь программный код:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head> <meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>File Upload Example</title> </head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="upload.py"
enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="file" name="filename" style="width:400px">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**upload.py**

```
import cgi , os
data = cgi.FieldStorage()
upload = data[ 'filename' ]
filename = os.path.basename( upload.filename )
with open( filename , 'wb' ) as copy :
copy.write( upload.file.read() )

print( 'Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n' )
print( '<!DOCTYPE HTML>' )
print( '<html lang="en">' )
print( '<head>' )
print( '<meta charset="UTF-8">' )
print( '<title>Python Response</title>' )
print( '</head>' )
print( '<body>' )
print( '<h1>File Uploaded:' , filename , '</h1>' )
print( '<a href="upload.html">Back</a>' )
print( '</body>' )
print( '</html>' )
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Все я разобрался. Оказывается сервер ругался на конструкцию with .. as. Поэтому я заменил

```
with open( filename , 'wb' ) as copy : 
copy.write( upload.file.read() )
```

на

```
f=open( filename , 'wb' ) 
f.write( upload.file.read() ) 
f.close()
```

Comment: Он ругается на отсутствие отступа а не на саму конструкцию...